# In objective-c, why 'typedef NSString * MyString' is preferred over 'typedef NSString MyString'?

Tags: objective-c

Option 1:
`typedef NSString MyString`

Option 2:
`typedef NSString * MyString`

---

#### Question

In Objective-C, both statement are valid, but from what I've seen people overwhelmingly choose option 2 over option 1. Is there a technical reason to that, or is it more of a convention?

---

#### Why I preferred option 1

Option 2 hides the fact that `MyString` is a pointer. This might be the intention, but in objective-c it's more often than not that you do want to know whether you're dealing with a primitive type or a reference type.

In C, at least the convention is to give it a name like `MyStringRef` to emphasize that it's a pointer, but I don't think I ever seen anyone does that in objective-c.

---

#### But option 1 doesn't play nicely with Swift

And then there's Swift. 
Both option 1 and option 2 works perfectly fine when bridged to swift, but if I try to mark option1 as a enum-

`typedef NSString MyString NS_STRING_ENUM;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT MyString * const MyStringOne;`

the compiler starts to freak out. Syntax highlight and auto-completion breaks all the time. And something like `var x = MyString.one` chokes the compiler straight out, leaving only the **Segmentation fault: 11** error.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine why someone would do either thing...and failing.  `NSString`, with or without *, is simple and immediately recognizable.

Comment: *I don't think I ever seen anyone does that in objective-c*.  There is a reason for that.  As @PhillipMills said, pretty much no one ever does typedefs for the purposes of class aliases.   What are you trying to do?

Comment: *I've seen people overwhelmingly choose option 2 over option1* Who? Where? No experienced Objective-C developer does such a thing.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... isn't that basically the way people do string 'enums' in objective-c? `typedef NSString * UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey`, `typedef NSString *NSErrorDomain`, etc. It's all over the SDK.

Comment: It's true I've never used it or seen people use it on anything other than NSString. Let me change the title to limit the scope.

Comment: This is the first time I hear about `NS_STRING_ENUM`. Interesting hack. Did you test it on Xcode 9?

Comment: `NS_STRING_ENUM` is a feature first added to swift 3 / Xcode 8 in 2016. I've tested the same setup in Xcode 9, but same result.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that this pattern is used when declaring “string enums” in Objective-C.

You ask why including the `*` in the `typedef` is preferred.

Well usually the reason is just one of *subjective* preference, either approach is valid. Note that Core Foundation uses type names such as `CFStringRef` where the `*` is hidden but the name contains `Ref` to indicate this, however Objective-C does not follow and use `NSStringRef`.

However you have found an *objective* reason to follow the usual pattern - the Swift compiler (at least in Xcode 8.2.1 I used and which one you used) is a sensitive creature and blows itself up with a memory fault if you use the other pattern.

First submit a bug to Apple (test first in Xcode 9 if you have it).

Then stick with the “preferred” pattern, unless you enjoy watching Swift commit compilercide ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I did file a radar- if swift not working with the _unusual_ pattern is by design, it'd be great if the compiler can catch and raise it as an error; if it's suppose to work, it'd be great if Apple can fix that bug :)